# Login MVC redirect to another page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a log-in page. When the user hits the log-in button the button will calla another action method. that action method will have two parameter. the user provided userid and password. then it do some validation and redirect to another action method according to the outcome. I am struggling with there. i guess this is pretty simple. i am new to MVC. Any help would be appriciated.

**View**

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Policy Assessment Tool</h1>
        <p class="lead">Are You Following Right?</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create","UserDatas")'">Register for a An Account</button>
        <h3><strong>OR</strong></h3>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <form class="form-signin" role="form" method="post">
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Sign-In to Continue</h2>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="input_domain_id" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Domain ID" autofocus required>
            <input type="password" name="input_domain_password" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Domain Password" required>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Verify_Login", "Ldap_Login_Verify")'">Login</button></p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        </form>
</div><!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Verify_Login(string input_domain_id, string input_domain_password)
//Log-in Logic
return View("Success")
```

Comment: what are you struggling with? it's not clear?

Comment: while calling the `Verify_login` from the submit button click `Login` how to pass the username and password to `verify_login` action?

Comment: check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482546/Creating-a-custom-user-login-form-with-NET-Csharp or this http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/how-to-create-login-page-using-aspnet-mvc4.html

Comment: i don't want that. i just want my controller action to get executed show me the result

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using form tag use Html.BeginForm HtmlHelper and pass Model from Controller to View for the best practice. Here is link for you to get [Getting Started With MVC5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but i dont need a model for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the mark up above you need not worry about it, When the form is posted the values will get bound to the parameters of the action method, As the parameter names are similar to the form field names.

The above concept is called model binding. The below two links should give you a good idea on the same.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710776/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-An-Absol
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx

I have tried to compile a simple example below.

Lets assume there is a view like below.

```
@model string 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Injection";
}

 <h2>Injection</h2>

 @using(Html.BeginForm())
{
        <div id="formDetails">
              @Html.TextBox("UserName")
       </div>
       <div>
              <input type="submit" id="btnTest" value="Click Me" />
       </div>
}
```

The Action method for the same would be like

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Injection(string UserName)
    {
        return View("Injection");

    }
```

So when i click on the submit button, The form is posted , Since the ViewName is injection, and there is a corresponding action method called injection it will automatically hit that action method. Since the parameter name of the method and field is the same, What ever value is there in the username textbox will get automatically bound to the method parameter.